# React JS Multiple submit Buttons react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

im using react-hook-form for form validation and submission ,everything work's fine with single submit type button, now i need to have three buttons  , "Save Draft" ,"Preview Data Values in Page" ,and "Submit for approval " ,i can opt-out for a Mode Selection radio Buttons ,But wanted to have three button submit function, which needs form data . adding onchnage for input fields will work ,but form validation needs to write again .

```
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  function NeedTohaveFormDataHere1(Data) {

   } function NeedTohaveFormDataHere2(Data) {

   }
    return (  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     <Headers />

  <input name="firstName" ref={register} placeholder="First name" />

  <input name="lastName" ref={register} placeholder="Last name" />

  <select name="category" ref={register}>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="A">Category A</option>
    <option value="B">Category B</option>
  </select>
  <button onClick={NeedTohaveFormDataHere1}>
   Save Draft
  </button > 
  <button onClick={NeedTohaveFormDataHere2}>
    Preview
  </button>  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
 );
 }
```

onSubmit function will get form data  ,how to get form data in other two button functions ?

sloved .. with

```
  <button onClick={handleSubmit(NeedTohaveFormDataHere1)}>
   Save Draft
  </button > 
  <button onClick={handleSubmit(NeedTohaveFormDataHere2)}>
    Preview
  </button>
```

Comment: This question is too weak in terms of explanation. Please give proper code and explanation

Comment: added example code

Comment: @KiranKumar Still really weak. Would you mind showing more detail? Did you remove the onSubmit from the form also? This doesn't provide enough to help.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and I resolved it the following way:

I have two buttons, the first bottom validates and submits the form normally. The second button only validates and calls a custom function.

I'm assuming you have the situation. One button to save and one to store a draft.

```jsx
<form id="example-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnSave)}>
  <IconButtonTooltip
    form="example-form"
    title="Only save"
  >
    <SaveIcon className={classes.icon} />
  </IconButtonTooltip>

  <IconButtonTooltip
    form="example-form"
    title="Save and sign"
    onClick={handleSubmit(handleOnSingAndSave)}
  >
    <SignatureIcon className={classes.icon} />
  </IconButtonTooltip>
</form>

const handleOnSingAndSave  = () => {
  // Handle things...
}
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 12):

You can use handleSubmit in multiple place.

```
const handleSubmitDraft=()=>{
  handleSubmit(aync(data)=>{...})()

}
const handleSubmitPreview=()=>{
  handleSubmit((data)=>{...})()
}
```

```
<button onClick={handleSubmitDraft}>
   Save Draft
</button > 
<button onClick={handleSubmitPreview}>
    Preview
</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

**if you have to handle the multiple submit buttons in react-hook-form**

*1. remove your submit method from the form tag and add it to your button click*

*2. move your submit buttons outside the form tag*

```
const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

<form>
 <input />
 <input />
</form>

<button onClick={handleSubmit((d) => console.log(d))} > Save </button>
<button onClick={handleSubmit((d) => console.log(d))} > Draft </button>
```

Comment: You call the same method with 2 different buttons.

Comment: I like this solution because it can actually move the submit buttons out of the form and put them anywhere I need.

Comment: This works as intended. I do however experience issues with lists not updating info until page is rendered again. Submit aka. save works and updates my list, but Add to List is not  firing of the render, but post data to state.

Answer (score 2):

Add a name attribute to your button. Then:

JavaScript

```
  async function onSubmit(values, e) {

    const submitter = e?.nativeEvent?.submitter;
    console.log(submitter?.name);
```

TypeScript

```
  async function onSubmit(
    values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>,
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>,
  ) {
    if (!(e.nativeEvent instanceof SubmitEvent)) return;
    const submitter = e?.nativeEvent?.submitter as HTMLButtonElement;
    if (!(submitter instanceof HTMLInputElement)) return;
    console.log(submitter?.name);
```

CanIuse SubmitEvent is safe: https://caniuse.com/?search=SubmitEvent

Comment: This is the answer. Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving name and type to a button and catch it using window.event.submitter.name.

```html
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 
    
    <button type="submit" name="draft">Draft</button> 

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} > ...
```

```js
    const handleSubmit = () => { 
    const buttonType=window.event.submitter.name // will return draft or submit and you can handle it using switch case.

    if(buttonType==="submit"){
    //HANDLE SUBMIT FUNCTION
    return;
    }

    if(buttonType==="draft"){
     //HANDLE DRAFT FUNC
    return;
    }

    }
```

But this solution [doesn't work in safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229660)

Answer (score 1):

I used yup with [resolver](https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers#quickstart) for validation so my answer might differ. I also used [trigger](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger) to validate without submitting. I also reset the form so that it won't be marked 'dirty' after saving.

```
export default function MyForm(props) {
  const {
    control,
    reset,
    trigger,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { isDirty },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onBlur",
    shouldUnregister: true,
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      id: "",
      //rest of values
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });  


  const handleOnSubmit = async (event) => {
    if(!isDirty){
      //navigate out of page
    } else {
      //save and exit
    }
  }

  const handleOnSave = async () => {
    trigger(); //triggers validation for whole form
    const formValue = getValues();
    const isValid = schema.isValidSync(formValue);
    if(isValid){
      //await save actions
      if(savedSuccessfully){
        reset(formValue);
        //anything else
      }
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: Nice answer with good hints on the useForm API.

Answer (score 1):

You Can add name or id to your button and check the button type as in modern browsers button type is submit by default

```
<button  name="submit">Submit</button> 
    
    <button  name="draft">Draft</button> 

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} > ...

function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

            const buttonType = event.submitter.getAttribute("name");

            switch (buttonType) {
                case "submit":
                    // Handle submit button click
                    alert("Submit button clicked");
                    break;
                case "draft":
                    // Handle draft button click
                    alert("Save Draft button clicked");
                    break;
                default:
                    // Handle other cases if needed
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem, I solved it by adding an onClick event to each submit button with a [setValue() function](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/setvalue). Example:

```html
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data.method)
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <button type='submit' name='A' {...register('method')} onClick={() => setValue('method', 'A')}>A button</button>
    <button type='submit' name='B' {...register('method')} onClick={() => setValue('method', 'B')}>B button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it in the next way:

`onSubmit` - form submission handler

```
                  <Button type="submit">Post</Button>
                  <Button
                    appearance="stroke"
                    onClick={handleSubmit((data) =>
                      onSubmit({
                        ...data,
                        status: CreateResumeRequestStatusEnum.Draft,
                      })
                    )}
                  >
                    Save for later
                  </Button>
```