# submit child form that was inside another form and prevent submitting parent form, react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am in the situation that I have to run function while submitting child form that was located inside another form and while I was submitting child form, parent form also running submit function, I give different id's and htmlFor of form attributes for the form but problem is not being solved. I am using react-hook-form

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful to you. [Link](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1005#:~:text=I%20fixed%20the%20problem%20I%20had%20to%20remove%20onSubmit%20of%20form%20tag%20and%20add%20it%20on%20onClick%20button%20%3A))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JS Multiple submit Buttons react-hook-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176755/react-js-multiple-submit-buttons-react-hook-form)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, it does. Actually, I saw that answer a long time ago and 2 days ago I added the answer to this question, but it got deleted by review. I didn't understand why?. 
Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Because your answer was basically only a link. You should accept the duplicate, so your question is closed as a duplicate to that other question.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening due to the event propagating. I've encountered and resolved this issue, so sharing my solution might help you too.

- Solution 1

use the stopPropagation to avoid unintended Actions

```js
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return handleSubmit(yourSubmitFunction)(e);
  }}
  id={formId}
>
  Your Form Content
</form>
```

- Solution 2

Remove the type = "submit" from your button.

```
<button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}> submit </button>
```